# JQuery Add Class when bottom of div reaches top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to add a class when the bottom of a div reaches the top of the window, but am not sure of how to do it.
I have managed to add the class when the top of the div gets to the top of the window, but am not having much luck with the bottom of the div.

Code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var menuLinksTop = $('.container').offset().top;  

var menuLinks = function(){  
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

    if (scrollTop > menuLinksTop) {   
        $('header').addClass('black-links');  
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('black-links');   
    }
};

menuLinks();  

$(window).scroll(function() {  
    menuLinks();  
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use javascript's `getBoundingClientRect()` method, watch `$(window).scroll` event, and look at element's rectangle, its `bottom` value will give you what you need (if it's negative, your element is all the way up)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($("div.watch")[0].getBoundingClientRect());
    if ($("div.watch")[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom < 0)
        alert ("i'm out :3");
});
```

see jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ja5nnbwr/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add the height of the div. Assuming it is the `.container` :

```
var menuLinksTop = $('.container').offset().top + $('.container').height();
```

Comment: For some reason it adds the class before the bottom of the div reaches the top of the page

Comment: Maybe because you have padding and/or margin. Use `outerHeight()` or `outerHeight(true)` for that. See the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)